# Understanding logic of SpriteKit animation with texture atlases

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, textures

I just don't get it. For example: I'm making a game with enemies. I made some pics and put it into atlas. I want an enemy to stand still before he will collide with hero and then implement an animation. Should I add first pic from atlas to represent an enemy at first and then somehow add all atlas to that pic to animate it? Also, if I want to make the size of an enemy as twice the hero size: do I need to code it only for the first sprite (if I need to add it first) or for every sprite one after another or even the whole atlas itself? I can't understand how to interact with them!
Also, I'm trying to make game universal, is that correct to name sprites like enemy001@1x.png; enemy001(at)2x.png; enemy001(at)3x.png and put it in one atlas? I'll appreciate any help with this, thanks!
I'm coding it with swift if that matters.

Comment: You need to read a bit more before proceeding. I suggest you start with this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html and then try out a couple of tutorials from here http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: Well, I did! I'm okay with regular xcassets but atlases are something terrifying for me. I also did Ray Wenderlich tutorial for atlases (http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases) But they aren't answering my questions as: how to resize something whose textures are into atlas by arranging it size property of a node (like I need to resize every sprite or not) or proper image naming. Ray suggests to name them @2x~ipad but I saw just @2x for example for universal devices. And so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too confusing in what your are specifically asking.

> "I can't understand how to interact with them!"

is not a good question. You need to be more precise and break it down into several questions if need be. However, below are some pointers which might clarify some issues for you.

1. You typically preload a texture atlas to avoid delays during your game play.
2. When you init a SKSpriteNode you can either use a texture (preferred when using an atlas) or an image.
3. To animate a sprite you run a sequence of images. There are several ways of accomplishing that. For example: `-(SKAction *)animateWithTextures:(NSArray *)textures timePerFrame:(NSTimeInterval)sec` would run an animation sequence of images placed into the NSArray.
4. Sizing for different screen sizes has been asked numerous times on StackOverflow. Do a search and see what comes up.

Comment: Thank you, @sangony! I agree, I should have builded my question better. Few more questions if you don't mind. I assume this is the Swift equivalent for your Obj-C code `let Action = SKAction.animateWithTextures(self.someArray, timePerFrame: )` ? So, in order to animate this I should make an array and append every texture from my atlas to it, am I right? And this is what I need to do with resizing too?

Comment: @Burundanga - I am not well versed in Swift but your code looks to be the same one. Correct on the array for animation. As for resizing, you will have to have different sized pics if you go the route of changing size based on device but before you go charging off making all different sizes, look at the SKScene.scaleMode property. Also read the section starting with "An SKTextureAtlas object" as it explains a lot of what you are asking. (click the 'more') https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTextureAtlas/index.html